# Parallel processing of Task<T> objects

Tags: c#, recursion, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, task

I am crawling web pages starting with the original URL and following any links recursively to determine the email address listed on these pages. I have used VS2015 and .net 4.6 to make use of the abstraction/ simplicity tasks provide over threading.

I have the page download working recursively but still the application has a serious bottleneck, it seems. With the simple code below, how can the flow be made to be more able to process in parallel each web page to interrogate the content for emails, and subsequent url links?

It seems tasks may be able to be started in tandem such that all urls found on a page can simultaneously be added to the next iteration of the looping logic? or do tasks now handle this under the hood?

below is my code, please offer some explanation so i can better understand the solution as i am just starting with tasks. (code is making use of HTML agility pack)

```
List<PageEmail> lstEmailData = new List<PageEmail>();

private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    getWEbData("http://localhost:801/"); //starting url
}

private async void getWEbData(string url) {
    Task<string> getHTMLTask = AccessTheWebAsync(url);
    string PageData = await getHTMLTask;

    var html = new HtmlDocument();
    html.LoadHtml  (PageData);

    var emails = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
      .Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value)
      .Where(href => href.StartsWith("mailto:")) // keep emails, skipp links
      .ToList();

    lstEmailData.Add(new PageEmail(url, emails));

    var urls = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
     .Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value)
     .Where(href => !href.StartsWith("mailto:")) // skip emails, find only url links
     .ToList();

    foreach (string s in urls) {
        getWEbData(s);
    }

}

async Task<string> AccessTheWebAsync(string URL)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient() { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1000000 };
    Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync(URL);
    return await getStringTask;
}
```

Comment: Can you upgrade to .NET 4.5? Or at least .NET 4.0? There are newer technologies and libraries available that would be a big help, but they only support newer platforms.

Comment: sorry, fat fingered that. I am on visual studio 2015 and .net 4.6

Comment: You could certainly change your foreach loop into a parallel construct to help BUT there are typically limits on how many simultaneous requests a server will let you make so you aren't going to see as much speed up as you may hope. PS a better way to handle this is with a Queue of urls to go visit, e.g. http://blog.abodit.com/2010/03/a-simple-web-crawler-in-c-using-htmlagilitypack/

Comment: @kacalapy You have multiple issues in your code. The first and most important, you are introducing race condition  lstEmailData.Add(new PageEmail(url, emails));  as List<T> is not thread safe, you must use something like ConcurrentBag instead. The second issue is, that you are chaining some tasks in blocking scenario, AccessTheWebAsync is async(so implemented as Task) and you await it, yet inside the method you are already awaiting task result, is wasting resources only. And the third issue is, that you can not detect completion of your algorithm and in reality, it can live forever...

Comment: @IanMercer foreach is calling async method, should be parallel...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core problem is probably that you're being limited by the remote server, which you have no control over. There's also the possibility that you may be limited by the (old) default connection limit in .NET; try setting `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` to `int.MaxValue` at the beginning of your process. Other than that, there's not much you can do.

Since you are learning `async`, you should know that it's best to avoid `async void`. Ideally, `getWEbData` should return a `Task`, and this change allows you to treat the "child" URLs as "child" tasks. This is especially useful for propagating errors correctly:

```
private async void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  await GetWebDataAsync("http://localhost:801/"); //starting url
}

private async Task GetWebDataAsync(string url) {
  var urls = ...;

  var urlTasks = urls.Select(s => GetWebDataAsync(s));
  await Task.WhenAll(urlTasks);
}
```

Comment: thanks, that helps errors but doesn't really allow multiple async operations of getWEbData(newURL) to run all separate threads in tandem. I belie this to be the ultimate design of processing many web pages in the least time. My logic seems to sequential and im looking to port it to be more parallel.

Comment: @kacalapy: It is concurrent, but not parallel. Multiple threads are unnecessary, since these are I/O-bound operations. This code will send an unbounded number of simultaneous requests, limited only by your hardware, bandwidth, and server-side throttling.